# Resizing image inside div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs and I wanted to resize images inside in those divs but they should allways fill div and constrain proportions.

Like this one:
http://www-07.ibm.com/sg/60/

If you try to resize them, they will allways fill their divs and images will allways keep their proportions.

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
        <img src="imgs/photo1.jpg" class="photo1">  
</div>
<div class="two">
        <img src="imgs/photo2.jpg" class="photo2">  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:50%; 
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.two{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

How do I style those images to look like this?

http://www-07.ibm.com/sg/60/

Comment: you need this:

    .one img, .two img
    {
       width:100%;
    }

Comment: You are trying to mimic IBM's style with only CSS, they are using JS to change margins and such... You will need JS to do this, or use the image as a background and use the background-size CSS3 property (which is less compatible with old browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Site is using jquery plugin for the effect, however you can get the same by css3 `background-size:cover` property.

What you have to do is :

Remove source image and give it through background and use `background-size:cover`.

```
<div class="one">

</div>

.one{
float:left;
width:50%;
height:50%; 
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background: url("path to image") no-repeat center center;
background-size : cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something here, but if I understand your question correctly, you can just add:

```
width: 100%;
```

to your `img` tags and they will always fill the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.one img, .two img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would get the best result by not using the  tag, but instead make these background images with the attribute:

```css
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
```